# ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries

Tags: sql-server

I get the following error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, sub queries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

When I try to run this query:

```
SELECT
MK_NAMA_KELAB AS "Nama Kelab",
MK_NO_AHLI AS "No Ahli",
convert(varchar(10),MK_TKH_KEAHLIAN_MULA,103) AS "Tarikh Mula",
convert(varchar(10),MK_TKH_KEAHLIAN_HINGGA,103) AS "Tarikh Hingga",
(MK_JUMLAH_YURAN) AS "Jumlah Yuran",
CASE  STATUS 
    WHEN 'Draf' THEN concat( '<a href =''','index.php?page=page_wrapper&','','menuID=26124&','pe_id=',PE_ID,'&','role=STAFF','''>',
                                          STATUS,'</a>')
    WHEN 'Sedang Dalam Pantauan' THEN concat('<a href =''','index.php?page=page_wrapper&','','menuID=26167','&','status=',STATUS,'&','pe_id=',PE_ID,'&','role=STAFF','''>',
                                          STATUS,'</a>' )                
    ELSE  concat('<a href =''','index.php?page=page_wrapper&','','menuID=26167&','pe_id=',PE_ID,'&','role=STAFF','''>',STATUS,'</a>')
END AS "Status"
FROM (
SELECT MK_PE_ID AS PE_ID,
MK_NAMA_KELAB,MK_NO_AHLI,
MK_TKH_KEAHLIAN_MULA,
MK_TKH_KEAHLIAN_HINGGA,
MK_JUMLAH_YURAN,
(SELECT LHP_NAMA FROM LKP_HR_PERAKUAN WHERE LHP_ID=
(isnull(
(SELECT PP_STATUS FROM E_PENGESAHAN_PERMOHONAN WHERE PP_ID =
 (SELECT MAX(PP_ID) FROM E_PENGESAHAN_PERMOHONAN WHERE PP_PE_ID=MK_PE_ID)),
(SELECT LP_STATUS FROM E_LOG_PERMOHONAN WHERE LP_ID =
 (SELECT MAX(LP_ID) FROM E_LOG_PERMOHONAN WHERE LP_PE_ID=MK_PE_ID))))) STATUS
FROM E_MAKLUMAT_KEAHLIAN
JOIN E_PERMOHONAN_ELAUN ON PE_ID=MK_PE_ID
WHERE PE_STF_ID = (
    SELECT STF_ID 
    FROM HR_STAF_PERIBADI SP 
    JOIN PRUSER PP ON PP.USERNAME = STF_USERNAME
    WHERE PP.USERID = '{SESSION|userID}')

ORDER BY MK_TARIKH_SIMPAN DESC)
```

Comment: As the error message states, you are using ORDER BY in a subquery (your FROM SELECT).

Comment: I've rolled back the edit to your question. Please don't delete the content after it's gotten answers, and you definitely shouldn't be trying to delete content from those answers.

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably about this subquery:

```
FROM (
SELECT MK_PE_ID AS PE_ID,
...
ORDER BY MK_TARIKH_SIMPAN DESC)
```

A subquery returns an unordered set, so ordering it doesn't make sense.  SQL Server will raise an error when you try to order without a purpose.

Move the `order by` to the outer query:

```
FROM    (
        SELECT MK_PE_ID AS PE_ID,
        ...
        ) as SubQueryAlias
ORDER BY MK_TARIKH_SIMPAN DESC
```

Subqueries also require an alias.

Comment: The order by is not in the subquery.

Comment: @Mihai: Good point, it was another subquery it seems, right after the `from`

Answer (score 0):

Try following query. See I don't know your table structure.But the problem is you add order by inside "From".

```
    SELECT MK_NAMA_KELAB AS "Nama Kelab",MK_NO_AHLI AS "No Ahli",convert(varchar(10),MK_TKH_KEAHLIAN_MULA,103) AS "Tarikh Mula",convert(varchar(10),MK_TKH_KEAHLIAN_HINGGA,103) AS "Tarikh Hingga",(MK_JUMLAH_YURAN) AS "Jumlah Yuran",
CASE  STATUS 
    WHEN 'Draf' THEN concat( '<a href =''','index.php?page=page_wrapper&','','menuID=26124&','pe_id=',PE_ID,'&','role=STAFF','''>',
                                          STATUS,'</a>')
    WHEN 'Sedang Dalam Pantauan' THEN concat('<a href =''','index.php?page=page_wrapper&','','menuID=26167','&','status=',STATUS,'&','pe_id=',PE_ID,'&','role=STAFF','''>',
                                          STATUS,'</a>' )                
    ELSE  concat('<a href =''','index.php?page=page_wrapper&','','menuID=26167&','pe_id=',PE_ID,'&','role=STAFF','''>',STATUS,'</a>')
END AS "Status",
MK_TARIKH_SIMPAN
FROM (
            SELECT MK_PE_ID AS PE_ID,
            MK_NAMA_KELAB,
            MK_NO_AHLI,
            MK_TKH_KEAHLIAN_MULA,
            MK_TKH_KEAHLIAN_HINGGA,
            MK_JUMLAH_YURAN,
            MK_TARIKH_SIMPAN,
            (
                SELECT LHP_NAMA FROM LKP_HR_PERAKUAN 
                WHERE LHP_ID=
                            (isnull(
                                        (SELECT PP_STATUS FROM E_PENGESAHAN_PERMOHONAN WHERE PP_ID =
                                                (SELECT MAX(PP_ID) FROM E_PENGESAHAN_PERMOHONAN WHERE PP_PE_ID=MK_PE_ID)
                                        ),
                                        (SELECT LP_STATUS FROM E_LOG_PERMOHONAN WHERE LP_ID =
                                                        (SELECT MAX(LP_ID) FROM E_LOG_PERMOHONAN WHERE LP_PE_ID=MK_PE_ID)
                                        )

                                    ))
            ) STATUS
            FROM E_MAKLUMAT_KEAHLIAN
            JOIN E_PERMOHONAN_ELAUN ON PE_ID=MK_PE_ID
            WHERE PE_STF_ID = (
                SELECT STF_ID 
                FROM HR_STAF_PERIBADI SP 
                JOIN PRUSER PP ON PP.USERNAME = STF_USERNAME
                WHERE PP.USERID = '{SESSION|userID}'
    )

)
ORDER BY MK_TARIKH_SIMPAN DESC
```